# draggable revert not work dynamically

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I create many div dynamically and add them draggable dynamically.but there is some problem. I want to revert false OR invalid when I drag to specific div whose class is droppable. How can I do this dynamically.

```
<img class="droppable" src=""></img>
 <div id="pi"></div>
<input type="button" id="ok">

 <script>
    var new_id=0;         
    $("#ok").click(function () {
    new_id = new_id + 1;
    var increase = new_id;
    var hidden = "<div class='hidden" + increase + " list-group'>
                  <span class='one" + increase + " list-group-item'></span>
                  <span class='two" + increase + " list-group-item'></span>
                  <span class='three" + increase + " list-group-item'></span>
                  <span class='four" + increase + " list-group-item'></span>";
     $(".hidden" + increase + "").draggable({ revert: true });//here revert invalid make error
     $("#pi").append(hidden);
      });
</script>
```

I also try this but it is not work

```
$(".droppable").mouseover(function(){    
    $(".draggable").draggable("option","revert","false");    
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending element only after call `.draggable` for it. Switch places of these calls:

```
$('#api').append(hidden);
$(".hidden" + increase + "").draggable({ revert: true });
```

Comment: Are there is no one able to answer this question.